# When is $\small \gcd(2n^7\!+1,{3n^3\!+2})>1,$ i.e. when is $\frac{2n^{7}+1}{3n^{3}+2}$ reducible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fractions

How can I ind the values of $n\in \mathbb{N}$  that make the fraction $\frac{2n^{7}+1}{3n^{3}+2}$ reducible ?

I don't know any ideas or hints how I solve this question.

I think we must be writte $2n^{7}+1=k(3n^{3}+2)$ with $k≠1$

Comment: For the fraction to be reducible does not require it to be an integer. You need only that the GCD of the numerator and denominator be greater than 1.

Comment: **Hint :** Divide the numerator by denominator and find out the remainder .

Comment: What is the context of this question? It can be solved using the _resultant_ of the polynomials $2n^7+1$ and $3n^3+2$, but I don't know if that solution will be helpful to you.

Comment: Experiment suggests that the solution is $n\equiv435\pmod{1163}$

Comment: @saulspatz can you drop solution please!

Comment: I don't have a solution.  I just wrote a little python script to check $n$ up to $10000$ and that's what I found.  It's easy to confirm that all such values work.  I don't how to prove that that they are the only ones, and the only reason I have to believe they are is that I haven't found any others.

Comment: @saulspatz , could you please tell me the least '$n$' for which this expression is reducible?

Comment: What is the smallest positive $n$ congruent to $435\pmod{1163}$?

Comment: So you mean $435$??

Comment: I greatly expanded my answer to highlight the close relationship with the Euclidean gcd algorithm .

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  The greatest common divisor $g$ of of $2n^7+1$ and $3n^3+2$ must also divide $$3(2n^7+1)-2n^4(3n^3+2)=3-4n^4$$ then $g$ must also divide $$4n(3n^3+2)-3(4n^4-3)=8n+9$$  Then $g$ must divide $$ 3n^4(8n+9)-8(3n^3+2)=27n^2-16$$

Continuing in this manner, we eventually find that $g$ must divide $1163$ which is prime.  So any solution satisfies $$3n^3+2\equiv0\pmod{1163}$$

The only solution to this is is $n\equiv435\pmod{1163}$ which I found with a python script, though I imagine there's a way to do it with a pencil.

It's easy to verify that also $2\cdot435^7+1\equiv0\pmod{1163}$, so the complete solution is $$n\equiv435\pmod{1163}.$$

**EDIT**

Daniel Wainfleet's answer shows the right way to find $435$.

Comment: $435^7=3^7. 5^7.29^7$... $29^2=841\equiv -322\mod 1163.$ Compute $29^4\equiv (-322)^2\equiv X$ and $29^6\equiv -322 X\equiv Y$  and $29^7\equiv 29 Y.$ And so on. Another way might be to re-arrange & re-write the argument to have all "iff" so as to avoid major arithmetic but I haven't  tried this...........+1

Comment: This is essentially a special case of the Euclidean algorithm - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $p$ is prime.

If $p$ divides $2n^7+1$ & $3n^3+2$

then $p$ divides $2(2n^7+1)-(3n^3+2)=n^3(4n^4-3)$

then $p$ divides $4n^4-3$ ( See Footnote )

then $p$ divides $2(4n^4-3)+3(3n^3+2)= n^3(8n+9)$

then $p$ divides $8n+9$ (See Footnote)

then $p$ divides $9(3n^3+2)-2(8n+9)=n(27n^2-16)$

then $p$ divides $27n^2-16$ (See Footnote)

then $p$ divides $9(27n^2-16)+16(8n+9)=n(243n+128)$

then $p$ divides $243n+128$ (See Footnote)

then $p$ divides $9(243n+128)-128(8n+9)=1163$

then $p=1163$ because $p$ and $1163$ are both prime

then $8n+9\equiv 0 \mod 1163$ so $n\equiv 435 \mod 1163$

So $\gcd (2n^7+1, 3n^3+2)>1\implies n\equiv 435 \mod 1163.$ And we may  verify  that $n\equiv 435 \mod 1163\implies 2n^7+1\equiv 3n^3+2\equiv 0 \mod 1163\implies \gcd (2n^7+1,3n^3+2)>1.$

Footnote. Suppose $A,B,C, D$ are integers with $A>0$ and $C>0,$ and  $p$ divides $n^A(Bn^C+D).$ Since $p$ is prime, $p$ divides $n^A$ or $p$ divides $Bn^C+D.$ Now if prime $p$ divides $n^A$ then $p$ divides $n$ and hence $p$ divides $2n^7$, BUT if $p$ also divides $2n^7+1$ then the prime $p>1$ divides $(2n^7+1)-(2n^7)=1,$ which is absurd. So instead, $p$ must divide $Bn^C+D.$

Comment: Of course!  $8n+9\equiv0\pmod{1163}$  I knew I was missing something easy.

Comment: Manual arithmetic error of mine. I fixed my A after seeing @saulpatz A, which appeared while I was typing & editing mine.

Comment: This is essentially a special case of the Euclidean algorithm - see my answer.

Comment: This is essentially a special case of the Euclidean algorithm - see my answer, where I also give a couple quick ways to compute the above-omitted congruence $\, n\equiv -9/8\equiv 435\pmod{\!1163}$  by trivial mental arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

Let $d = \gcd(2n^7+1, 3n^3+2)$. Then since $2n^7+1 \ | \ 2^3n^{21}+1$ and $3n^3 + 2 \ | \ 3^7n^{21}+2^7$, we must have $$d \ | \ 3^7(2^3n^{21}+1) - 2^3(3^7n^{21}+2^7) \quad\Rightarrow\quad d \ | \ 1163.$$

Since $1163$ is a prime, if the fraction is reducible, $1163 \ | \ 3n^3 + 2$. Since $1163 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, $n^3 \equiv -2\cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 587 \pmod{1163}$ has one unique solution modulo $1163$.

Fermat's little theorem tells you that $n \equiv n^{1163} \equiv n^{2325} \equiv n^{3\times 775}\pmod{1163}$. So the answer should be $n \equiv 587^{775} \pmod{1163}$.

This is hard to solve by hand, so if you believe saulspatz's computation that $n \equiv 435 \pmod{1163}$, that is all the possible solutions.

Comment: We don't need to blindly believe that $\, -9/8\equiv 435\pmod{1163}\,$ since it can be computed in $20$ seconds of trivial mental arithmetic - see my answer.

Comment: Your answer is seen.

Answer (score 1):

This gcd is computable *purely mechanically* by a slight generalization of the Euclidean algorithm which allows us to scale by integers $\,c\,$ coprime to the gcd during the modular reduction step, i.e.

$$\bbox[8px,border:2px solid #c00]{(a,b)\, = \,(a,\,cb\bmod a)\ \ \ {\rm if}\ \ \ (a,c) = 1}\qquad\qquad  $$

which is true since $\,(a,c)= 1\,\Rightarrow\, (a,\,cb\bmod a) = (a,cb)  = (a,b)\ $ by Euclid. When computing the gcd of polynomials $\,f(n),g(n)$ with integer coef's, we can use such scalings to force the lead coef of the dividend to be divisible by the lead coef of the divisor, which enables the division to be performed with integer (vs. fraction) arithmetic. Let's do that in the example at hand (but you may find it helpful to first study  the simpler examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4098638/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3881931/242)).

$\!\begin{align}{\rm{This\,\ yields}\!: \ \ \ }(3n^3\!+2,\,2n^7\!+1) &\,=\, (3n^3\!+2,\,\color{#0a0}{8n+9})\ \ \ {\rm by}\ [\![1]\!]\ \text{ below,  $\,c = 3^2$}\\[.4em]
&\,=\, (\color{#90f}{-1163},\ \  8n+9)\ \ \ {\rm by}\, [\![2]\!]\ \text{ below,  $\,c = 8^3$}\end{align}$
$\!\!\!\begin{align}
&\bmod\:\! \color{#c00}{3n^3\!+2}^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\!\!\!:\,\  3^2(2n^7\!+1)\equiv 2n(\color{#c00}{3n^3})^2\!+9\,\equiv\, \color{#0a0}{8n+9},\, \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{3n^3\equiv -2}\,\qquad [\![1]\!]\\[.4em]
&\bmod\:\! \color{#0a0}{8n+9}\!:\ \   8^3(3n^3\!+2)\equiv 3(\color{#0a0}{8n})^3\!+ 2(8^3) \equiv  \color{#90f}{-1163},\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{8n\,\equiv \,-9}\:\!\qquad[\![2]\!] \end{align}$

So the gcd $\!=\! (1163,8n\!+\!9)\! >\! 1\! \iff\!$ prime $p\! =\! 1163\mid 8n\!+\!9\!$ $\iff\! \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #0a0]{n\equiv \color{90f}{435}\pmod{\!p}}\,$ by

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\,\ n\equiv\dfrac{\!\!-9}8\!\equiv 3\left[\dfrac{-3}8\right] \equiv 3\left[\dfrac{1160}8\right]\equiv 3[145]\equiv 435.\ \ $ [See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) for 5 more ways]

**Remark** $ $ Above $\,k \bmod a\,$ denotes some "simpler" $k'$ such that $\,k'\equiv k\pmod{\!a},\,$ not necessarily the *least* nonnegative such value. Here we are "simplifying" by reducing the degree in $\,n,\,$ i.e. essentially using the Euclidean algorithm for *polynomials* (the scaling by $\,c\,$ corresponds to a fraction-free form of the algorithm using the [Nonmonic Division Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242)).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3881931/242) for a simpler example.

Answer (score 1):

The extended euclidean algorithm for gcd (of polynomials with rational coefficients) also tells us that
 $$  \left(  2 x^{7}  + 1 \right)  \left(   { 1728 x^{2}  - 1944 x  + 2187 }  \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 \right)  \left(   { 1152 x^{6}  - 1296 x^{5}  + 1458 x^{4}  - 768 x^{3}  + 864 x^{2}  - 972 x  + 512 }  \right)  = 1163 $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(  2 x^{7}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x^{7}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x^{4}  - 4 x  }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 8 x  + 9 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 8 x  + 9 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 1728 x^{2}  - 1944 x  + 2187 }{ 512 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ -1163}{512 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 8 x  + 9 }{ 9 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ -1163}{512 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 4096 x  - 4608 }{ 10467 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x^{4}  - 4 x  }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x^{4}  - 4 x  }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 1728 x^{2}  - 1944 x  + 2187 }{ 512 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 576 x^{6}  - 648 x^{5}  + 729 x^{4}  - 384 x^{3}  + 432 x^{2}  - 486 x  + 256 }{ 256 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 1728 x^{2}  - 1944 x  + 2187 }{ 512 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 4096 x  - 4608 }{ 10467 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 1024 x^{7}  - 512 }{ 1163 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 1536 x^{3}  - 1024 }{ 1163 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{7}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 1728 x^{2}  - 1944 x  + 2187 }{ 1163 }  \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 1152 x^{6}  - 1296 x^{5}  + 1458 x^{4}  - 768 x^{3}  + 864 x^{2}  - 972 x  + 512 }{ 1163 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

Comment: It's *much* easier to use modular arithmetic as I explain in my answer. None of the Bezout coef's are needed. As usual - they only serve to obfuscate the essence of the matter and make the computation much more arduous.