# When does $2n-1$ divide $16(n^2-n-1)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

Find all integers $n$ such that 
$\dfrac{16(n^2-n-1)^2}{2n-1}$ 
is an integer.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Please clarify the range of $n$

Comment: I think $2n-1|16$ $2n-1|(n^2​-n-1)^2​$

Comment: thanks for the hint now i get the answer

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$16(n^2-n-1)^2{=(4n^2-4n+1-5)^2=\Big((2n-1)^2-5\Big)^2\\=
(2n-1)^4-10(2n-1)^2+25
}$$
therefore $${16(n^2-n-1)^2\over 2n-1}\in \Bbb Z\iff {25\over 2n-1}\in \Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 3):

This method is not necessarily the "fastest" way to solve this kind of problem, but its power resides in the fact that it always works.

First of all, expand the numerator (I know, this doesn't seem to help at all, but it does!). You get the expression $16n^4 -32n^3-16n^2+32n+16$.

Now perform the long division between that expression and your denominator $2n-1$ (think of these two expressions as if they were polynomials).

You obtain as quotient $8n^3-12n^2-14n+9$ and your remainder is the integer number $25$.

Since you wanted this division to be exact, this means that the remainder $25$ had to be divisible by $2n-1$. So you now try to equate $2n-1$ with every possible divisor of $25$. Those are $-25,-5,-1,1,5,25$. Each of these give a possible value of $n$: $-12,-2,0,1,3,13$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting off with the initial expression:
$$\frac{16(n^2-n-1)^2}{2n-1}$$
Completing the square:
$$=\frac{4^2(n^2-n-1)^2}{2n-1}$$
$$=\frac{(4n^2-4n-4)^2}{2n-1}$$
$$=\frac{((2n-1)^2-5)^2}{2n-1}$$
Some manipulation:
$$=(2n-1)^3(1-\frac{5}{(2n-1)^2})^2$$
Expanding the expression:
$$=(2n-1)^3-10(2n-1)+\frac{25}{2n-1}$$

Since the first two terms will always be integers,

If this expression is to be an integer, then:
$$(2n-1)= factor\ of\ 25$$
$$n=\frac{1+factor\ of\ 25}{2}$$
The factors of 5 are $\pm 1, \pm 5, \pm 25$

thus,

n=$1\pm1\over 2$

or

n=$1\pm 5 \over 2$

or

n=$1\pm 25 \over 2$

n=1,0,-2,3,-12,13

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\!\overbrace{{\rm numerator} = f(\color{#c00}{2n})}^{\textstyle\begin{align}{\ \ \ \ \ (4(n^2\,-\ n\ -\ 1))^2\\ = ((\color{#c00}{2n})^2\!-\!2(\color{#c00}{2n})\!-\!4)^2}\end{align}_{\phantom{|}}}\! $  & $\bmod  \overbrace{2n-1}^{\textstyle\color{#c00}{2n\equiv 1}}\!:\ f(\color{#c00}{2n})\equiv f(\color{#c00}1)\,$ by [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

**Remark** $ $ More generally we can use modular fractions and simply evaluate $\,f(x)\,$ at $\,\color{#c00}{n\equiv 1/2}\,$ or, equivalently we [can use](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242) the nonmonic division algorithm to work fraction-free. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3671880/242).

Answer (score 1):

Let $k = 2n-1$ then $$\dfrac{16(n^2-n-1)^2}{2n-1} = \dfrac{(4n^2-4n-4)^2}{2n-1}$$
$$ = \dfrac{((k+1)^2-2(k+1)-4)^2}{k} = {(k^2-5)^2\over k}$$

So $$k\mid (k^2-5)^2= k^4-10k^2+25$$ $$\implies k\mid 25 \implies k\in\{\pm 1, \pm 5,\pm 25\}$$