# Show that for all integers $n$, $\gcd(n^6 + 3n^2 + n + 4, n^2 + 1) = 1$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I got hold of the answer but I'm puzzled by two of the lines. Hoping someone can explain why how the solution is derived for the characters in **bold**.

First, let's observe $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

$n^6 + 3n^2 + n + 4$ can thus be expressed as:   //using symbolab calculator
$$(n^6+3n^2+n+4) = (n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1)+n$$

And $n^2 + 1$ can be expressed as:
$$n^2+1 = n(n)+1$$

Second, we observed that the Property of GCD is $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-kb, b)$, $∀k∈ℤ$

$\gcd(n^6 + 3n^2 + n + 4, n^2 + 1)$
$= \gcd(n^6+3n^2+n+ 4)-(n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1), n^2+1$   //using symbolab calculator
$= \gcd(n, n^2+1)$
$= \gcd(n, n^2+1-n(n))$
$= \gcd(n, 1) = 1$

The thing that I do NOT understand is why they did NOT use "**+n**" in the equation below.
$$= \gcd(n^6+3n^2+n+ 4)-(n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1), n^2+1$$

Shouldn't the **$+n$** be in since $kb$ is $(n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1)+n$?

Also, why do we need to minus off with "**n(n)**" in the second last line [$= \gcd(n, n^2+1-n(n))$]?

Appreciate any expert advice.

Thank you.

Comment: "Shouldn't the +n be in since "kb" is (n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1)+n ?"  Huh?  No.  The $b$ is $n^2 +1$ and the $k$ is $(n^4-n^2+4)$ so $kb$ is $(n^4-n^2+4)(n^2+1)$.  Why on earth did you put the $+n$ *in*?

Comment: "Also, why do we need to minus off with "n(n)" in the second last line [=gcd(n,n2+1−n(n))]?"  Because it will get us down to $1$ which is the perfect desire for a term in a gcd expression.

Comment: See [The Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm) for an explanation of what's happening. It is true that the stated gcd property is being used. However, the reason why one chooses a particular $k$ is outlined there, and it basically comes from polynomial division. You should read up on that algorithm before you try similar questions.

Comment: This is essentially figuring out that $\gcd(18, 103) = 1$.  $\gcd(18,103)=\gcd(18,103-5\cdot 18)=\gcd(18, 13) = \gcd(18-13, 13)=\gcd(5,13)=\gcd(5,13-2\cdot 5) =\gcd(5,3)=\gcd(5-3,3)=\gcd(2,3)=\gcd(2,3-1)=\gcd(2,1) = 1$.  Can you understand how that works?  They example given is *exactly* the same but with polynomials rather than integers.

Comment: They are using the (polynomial) euclidean algorithm $(a,b) = (a\bmod b,b)$ where $a\bmod b = a-kb$ is the *smaller* (degree) remainder left on [dividing the polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48963/242) $a$ by $b$, and $k$ is the quotient. In both steps the divisor has lead coef $1$ so the division is fraction free. As explained in the linked dupe, the key idea of the division algorithm is to choose the quotient so that the leading terms cancel - so reducing the degree.

Comment: Since we need only the remainder (not the quotient $k$) it's easier to use modular arithmetic as below
$$\begin{align}&\bmod n^2+1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#c00}{n^2})^3+3\color{#c00}{n^2}+n+4\equiv(\color{#c00}{-1})^3+3(\color{#c00}{-1})+n+4\equiv \color{#0a0}n\\[.2em]  
&\qquad\, \bmod\, n\!:\quad\ \ \color{#0a0}{n\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}n^2+1\equiv \color{#0a0}0^2+1\equiv 1\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242) and its links for how to handle the case when the lead coef of the divisor is not $\pm 1\ \ $

Comment: Thank you everyone for explaining. Especially @fleablood who has been especially helpful!  Muchos gracias!