# Prove $d \mid a^2b+1$ and $d \mid b^2a+1 \implies d \mid a^3+1$ and $d \mid b^3+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove for all $a, b, d$ integers greater than zero, that when $d$ is a divisor of both $a^2b+1$ and $b^2a+1$ then $d$ is also a divisor of both $a^3+1$ and $b^3+1$

---

There is a trivial case when $a = b$, but I found that there are more solutions, for example: $a = 1, b = 3, d = 2$. I tried to use equation $a^3+1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)$ but I am not sure how to progress.

Comment: $\bbox[4px,border:1px solid #c00]{ c,e\equiv 1\, \Rightarrow\, c^2/e\equiv 1}\ \ $ Put $\ c = -a^2b,\, e = -ab^2,\ $ so $\ {-}a^3\equiv c^2/e \equiv 1\ \ \ 
\small\bf QED\ \ $

Comment: Or we can **eliminate** $\,b\,$ via $\,\color{#c00}{b\equiv -a^2}\,$
 so $\,−1\equiv a\color{#c00}{b^2}\equiv a^{-3}\,$ so $\,a^3\equiv -1.\,$ This is a special case of using nonmonic ("fraction free") division in the **Euclidean algorithm** as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242), i.e. $\,(a^2b+1,ab^2+1)=(a^2b+1,a^3(ab^2+1))=(a^2b+1,(−1)^2+a^3),\,$
 i.e. before eval'ing $\,f(b)=ab^2+1\,$ at $\,b\equiv −a^{−2}\,$
 we first scale it by the unit $\,a^3\,$ to elminate all "fractions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $d \mid a^2\ b+1$ and $d \mid a\ b^2+1$ then $d \mid (1-b\ a^2)(a^2\ b+1)+a^3(a\ b^2+1) = a^3+1$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Said *equationally* it's that below. But it's easier to manipulate *units* (see my comment on the question)
$$\bmod d\!:\,\ \overbrace{1\equiv \color{#c00}{a^4b^2}}^{\!\!\!\!\textstyle (-1\equiv \color{#c00}{a^2b})^{\color{#c00}2}}\!\!\!\equiv \underbrace{a^3(\color{#0a0}{ab^2})\equiv -a^3}_{\textstyle \color{#0a0}{ab^2}\equiv -1\!}\: \Rightarrow\ d\mid a^3+1\qquad$$